# Solving non-linear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

For my research project I need to solve the following integral

```
I = 
  1/2 Integrate[π Sqrt[r[θ]^2 Sin[θ]^2] 
    Sqrt[r[θ]^2 + Derivative[1][r][θ]^2/
      (1 + 1/r[θ]^2 - 3/r[θ] + r[θ]^2)], 
    {θ, 0, 0.005}]
```

where  `r[θ]` is a solution of following differential equation

```
-2 r[θ] + 12 r[θ]^2 - 22 r[θ]^3 + 12 r[θ]^4 - 6 r[θ]^5 + 12 r[θ]^6 - 
   4 r[θ]^7 - 2 r[θ]^9 + 
   (Cot[θ] r[θ]^2 - 3 Cot[θ] r[θ]^3 + Cot[θ] r[θ]^4 + Cot[θ] r[θ]^6) 
     Derivative[1][r][θ] + 
   (-2 r[θ] + (15 r[θ]^2)/2 - 3 r[θ]^3 - 4 r[θ]^5) Derivative[1][r][θ]^2 + 
   Cot[θ] r[θ]^2 Derivative[1][r][θ]^3 + 
   (r[θ]^2 - 3 r[θ]^3 + r[θ]^4 + r[θ]^6) Derivative[2][r][θ]
```

with initial conditions `{r[0] == r0, r'[0] == 0}`.

It's a second order non-linear differential equation. The independent variable θ runs from `θ = {0, 0.005}`. There is a singularity at `θ = 0`, which can be avoided by taking `θ = 10^-10` (some small value). Then initial conditions modify to `{r[10^-10] == r0, r'[10^-10] == 0}`.

I have to choose `r0` such that by solving the above equation one should get `r[0.005] = 10000`. The initial guess for `r0` (depending upon the working precision) can be around `r0 = 199.958344`.

At the end, integral should gives value `I = 76.96884`.

I am solving this problem in *Mathematica* and getting answer like `I = 76.9844`.

Can you please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Your differential equation isn't actual an equation. Equations should have `==` somewhere.

Comment: Where you write `(r^′′)[θ]` in the above, do you really mean `Derivative[2][r][θ]`?

Comment: I'm set WorkingPrecision -> 30 and Integral is: I = 76.9843992958913645452412310988. Maybe this is the correct answer.

Comment: Dear Sjoerd C. de Vries, I have just given the expression for the Left hand side. The right hand side of the equation is zero. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Dear  @m_goldberg, Thank you for your time. Can you please post the full mathematica code here. I have also used WorkingPrecision -> 30, but didn't get the answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @m_Goldberg I had already changed `(r^′′)[θ]` to `r′′[θ]` (which is `Derivative[2][r][θ]`). For some reason you changed it back to `(r^′′)[θ]` .

Comment: Dear @ I_Mariusz, I got the same answer which you are getting. Unfortunately, it is not the right answer. Thank you very much for trying.

Comment: I have restored your edit in a form consistent with the rest of the expression. We were both editing at the same time and my changes over-wrote yours. Happens sometimes.

Comment: Dear @chandra. May be the problem lies here -> matlab's  numeric solver "bvp4c" is not perfect as we all assume.

Comment: *Dear me!* - I guess one might skip this kind of formality here; everyone here is on "first user name terms". ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following leads me to believe that the value of the integral as given by [I_Mariusz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26828/i-mariusz) is correct.

First, solve the ODE itself with `MaxStepFraction -> 10^-6`.

```
ϵ = 10^-50;
{s, t} = NDSolveValue[{-2 r[θ] + 12 r[θ]^2 - 22 r[θ]^3 + 12 r[θ]^4 - 6 r[θ]^5 + 
    12 r[θ]^6 - 4 r[θ]^7 - 2 r[θ]^9 + (Cot[θ] r[θ]^2 - 3 Cot[θ] r[θ]^3 + Cot[θ] r[θ]^4 +
    Cot[θ] r[θ]^6) Derivative[1][r][θ] + (-2 r[θ] + (15 r[θ]^2)/2 - 3 r[θ]^3 - 
    4 r[θ]^5) Derivative[1][r][θ]^2 + Cot[θ] r[θ]^2 Derivative[1][r][θ]^3 + (r[θ]^2 - 
    3 r[θ]^3 + r[θ]^4 + r[θ]^6) Derivative[2][r][θ] == 0, r'[ϵ] == 0, r[5/1000] == 10000}, 
    {r, r'}, {θ, ϵ, 5/1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxSteps -> 10^7, 
    MaxStepFraction -> 10^-6, Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {r'[ϵ] == 0, r[ϵ] == 199958364/1000000}}];
```

which yields (after a few hours of calculation) the interpolation functions for `r` and `r'`.

```
LogPlot[{s[θ], t[θ]}, {θ, ϵ, .005}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Note that the solution is growing faster than exponentially near `θ -> 0.005`.  The initial (called `r0` in the question) and final values of `r` are

```
{s[ϵ], s[5/1000]}
(* {199.95836405695030604588498996975119999174071797848, 
    10000.000000000000000005072133417578396839834109} *)
```

To estimate the accuracy of this solution, repeat the computation with `MaxStepFraction -> 10^-5`, which takes only several minutes, and compare the resulting solution, designated `{s5, t5}`, to `{s, t}`.

```
LogPlot[{Abs[s[θ] - s5[θ]]/s5[θ], Abs[t[θ] - t5[θ]]/t5[θ]}, {θ, ϵ, .005}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Agreement is excellent.  The integral can be computed by

```
π/2 NIntegrate[s[θ] Sin[θ] Sqrt[s[θ]^2 + t[θ]^2/(1 + 1/s[θ]^2 - 3/s[θ] + s[θ]^2)], 
    {θ, ϵ, 0.005}]
(* 76.98439929825058 *)
```

or by

```
sx = Flatten[s["Grid"]]; sy = s["ValuesOnGrid"]; ty = t["ValuesOnGrid"];
int = Interpolation[Table[{sx[[i]], sy[[i]] Sin[sx[[i]]] Sqrt[sy[[i]]^2 + 
   ty[[i]]^2/(1 + 1/sy[[i]]^2 - 3/sy[[i]] + sy[[i]]^2)]}, {i, Length[sx]}]];
π/2 Integrate[int[θ], {θ, ϵ, 0.005}]
(* 76.98439929486328 *)
```

The two results agree to ten significant figures.  I also have used `NIntegrate` with `WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 50`, as well as with other values of these two quantities.  Although `NIntegrate` then generates error messages, it still gives results agreeing with those above to nine significant figures.

I believe that we may safely conclude that the answer is approximately `76.9843992`.

Comment: "after a few hours of calculation" - wow, that hard, eh?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Thank you very much for your help. I think what you are saying is correct. And now I am convince that the numerical value of the integral should be I=76.98439 instead of I = 76.96884. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

At first we find `r0`:

```
 eq = {-2 r[\[Theta]] + 12 r[\[Theta]]^2 - 22 r[\[Theta]]^3 + 
 12 r[\[Theta]]^4 - 6 r[\[Theta]]^5 + 12 r[\[Theta]]^6 - 
 4 r[\[Theta]]^7 - 2 r[\[Theta]]^9 + (Cot[\[Theta]] r[\[Theta]]^2 - 
 3 Cot[\[Theta]] r[\[Theta]]^3 + Cot[\[Theta]] r[\[Theta]]^4 + 
 Cot[\[Theta]] r[\[Theta]]^6)*r'[\[Theta]] + (-2 r[\[Theta]] + (15 r[\[Theta]]^2)/2 - 
 3 r[\[Theta]]^3 - 4 r[\[Theta]]^5)*(r'[\[Theta]])^2 + 
 Cot[\[Theta]] r[\[Theta]]^2*(r'[\[Theta]])^3 + (r[\[Theta]]^2 - 
 3 r[\[Theta]]^3 + r[\[Theta]]^4 + r[\[Theta]]^6)*(r''[\[Theta]]) == 0}

 sol2 = With[{\[Epsilon] = 10^-50}, 
 r /. ParametricNDSolve[{eq, r[\[Epsilon]] == r0, 
 r'[\[Epsilon]] == 0}, r, {\[Theta], \[Epsilon], 5/1000}, {r0}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxStepFraction -> 0.00001, 
 MaxSteps -> 10^6]];
 sol3[r0_?NumericQ] := sol2[r0][5/1000];
 SetPrecision[
 FindRoot[sol3[r0] == 10000, {r0, 199.957, 199.959}, Method -> "Brent", 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50], 50]
```

> $\{r0\to 199.95836405695030604588494221489902476795675126277\}$

With **Maple** I have got `r0 = 199.96131889676149`,a very **big difference** in results.

Calculate the integral:

```
 sol = First@With[{\[Epsilon] = 10^-30},r /. NDSolve[{eq, 
 r[\[Epsilon]] == 199.95836405695030604588494221489902476795675126276935236196857881508093072408836, r'[\[Epsilon]] == 0}, 
  r, {\[Theta], \[Epsilon], 5/1000}, MaxStepFraction -> 0.00001, 
  MaxSteps -> 10^6, WorkingPrecision -> 30]];
  \[Epsilon] = 10^-30;
  i = (1/2)*NIntegrate[Pi*Sqrt[sol[\[Theta]]^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2]*Sqrt[sol[\[Theta]]^2 + 
  sol'[\[Theta]]^2/(1 + 1/sol[\[Theta]]^2 - 3/sol[\[Theta]] + 
  sol[\[Theta]]^2)], {\[Theta], \[Epsilon], 5/1000},WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxRecursion -> 10000]
```

> $i = 76.9843992958929803977886284771$

Plot:

```
Plot[{sol[\[Theta]], 199.95836}, {\[Theta], 0, 0.0051}, 
Prolog -> {Line[{{0.005, 0}, {0.005, 2000}}]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 0.0051}, {0, 2000}}, 
PlotLegends -> {"r[\[Theta]]", "r0"}]
```

[image]

With **Maple** I have got `i = 76.9843992970933`.In both programs results are almost similar.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by your last sentence?  Also, how did you obtain `I = 76.96884` in your question and how do you know that it is the right answer?

Comment: @Dear I_Mariusz, Thank you very much for trying. I have wrote the same kind of code which you have posted here and getting the same answer for Integral. It seems to me that the problem is with calculating r0. Unfortunately the published version of the paper, which I am trying to reproduce, has I = 76.96884. However, authors in that paper using matlab's bvp4c. Since, we are using Mathematica, may be the problem lies here. If you have any comments in this regard, I will highly appreciate that.

Comment: Dear  bbgodfrey, Please check the mathematica file posted by I_Mariusz to get r0 and I. For the answer, I am following a published paper where, I = 76.96884 was archived.

Comment: @Chandra Can you provide a link to the paper as it all sounds confusing as to whether I=76.96884 or not. What is correct and what is wrong. U said it is "unfortunate"...why? Sometimes ambiguous input can waste precious time on part of those who are trying to help.

Comment: @bbgodfrey.I do not know whether this is the correct answer.My last sentence->We can skip  and it is not no big deal.Sorry my English bad.(Google Translator not perfect yet)